# How to insert framework into repo lib create by CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I had a framework named `TCXXXXX.framework` can only be added to project by manual.

In addition, I had created a Share repo by CocoaPods's command `pod lib create STShare`.

I had try to add `TCXXXX.framework` and `TCXXXX.bundle` into STShare's Classes document. However, it work wired. `TCXXXX.framework` and `TCXXXX.bundle` changed to a document view in Xcode( The bundle and framework icon just disappeared).

By the way, it couldn't build succeed because `STShare` couldn't found the class in `TCXXX.framework`.

I want to know how to add framework to STShare repo by manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I answer by myself. (Too much time for answer, and I found by myself)

I can fulfill the requirement by specify `s.framework` line in `STShare.podspec` file.